# 2960x1440 stretching Android Camera Preview

Tags: java, android, android-camera, preview

I have a camera preview that works perfectly on almost all of the screens but when I tested my camera with `2960x1440` screen, which for example are on phones S8 and S9, the preview is really stretched.

I have included everything I have on setting the `preview size` for the Camera.

```
private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 2960;
private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1440;

/**
 * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, choose the smallest one that
 * is at least as large as the respective texture view size, and that is at most as large as the
 * respective max size, and whose aspect ratio matches with the specified value. If such size
 * doesn't exist, choose the largest one that is at most as large as the respective max size,
 * and whose aspect ratio matches with the specified value.
 *
 * @param choices           The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output
 *                          class
 * @param textureViewWidth  The width of the texture view relative to sensor coordinate
 * @param textureViewHeight The height of the texture view relative to sensor coordinate
 * @param maxWidth          The maximum width that can be chosen
 * @param maxHeight         The maximum height that can be chosen
 * @param aspectRatio       The aspect ratio
 * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
 */
private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth, int textureViewHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Size aspectRatio)
{
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    for (Size option : choices) {
        if (option.getWidth() <= maxWidth && option.getHeight() <= maxHeight &&
                option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w) {
            if (option.getWidth() >= textureViewWidth &&
                    option.getHeight() >= textureViewHeight) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            } else {
                notBigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }
    }
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0)
    {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else if (notBigEnough.size() > 0)
    {
        return Collections.max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else
    {
        return choices[0];
    }
}

/**
 * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, chooses the smallest one whose
 * width and height are at least as large as the respective requested values, and whose aspect
 * ratio matches with the specified value.
 *
 * @param choices     The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output class
 * @param width       The minimum desired width
 * @param height      The minimum desired height
 * @param aspectRatio The aspect ratio
 * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
 */
private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    for (Size option : choices) {
        if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w &&
                option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
            bigEnough.add(option);
        }
    }
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else {
        return choices[0];
    }
}


/**
 * Sets up member variables related to camera.
 * @param width  The width of available size for camera preview
 * @param height The height of available size for camera preview
 */
private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {

    System.out.println("Setup camera outputs.");
    try {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

        assert map != null;

        Size largest = Collections.max(
                Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                new CompareSizesByArea());

        mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class)); //640x480

        mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                width, height, mVideoSize);
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);
        int displayRotation =parentactivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        boolean swappedDimensions = false;

        switch (displayRotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270)
                {
                    swappedDimensions = true;
                }
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180)
                {
                    swappedDimensions = true;
                }
                break;
            default:
        }

        Point displaySize = new Point();
        parentactivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
        int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
        int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
        int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
        int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

        if (swappedDimensions) {
            rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
            rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
            maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
            maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
        }

        if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
            maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
        }
        if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
            maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
        }

        mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                maxPreviewHeight, mVideoSize);

        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        }
        Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
        mFlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (CameraAccessException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 /**
 * Creates a new {@link CameraCaptureSession} for camera preview.
 */
private void createCameraPreviewSession()
{
    if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        closePreviewSession();
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession)
                    {
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;

                        try {
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession)
                    {
                        showToast("Failed to configure camera.");
                    }
                }, null
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
/**
 * Configures the necessary {@link Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
 * This method should be called after the camera preview size is determined in
 * setUpCameraOutputs and also the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
 * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
 * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
 */
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == parentactivity) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation =parentactivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale = Math.max(
                (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
        matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
}
```

Since I do not quite understand what is wrong here when scaling the preview size to 2960x1440, I would be really thankful if someone could help me with this.

Just in case I have added a link to the complete code [Pastebin Link to Camera](https://pastebin.com/thajnhf0)

Comment: What do you mean by stretched. Can you give an example of how it looks on a regular phone and on a hi-res phone?

Comment: @zipo13 I didnt get a phone to screenshot it, will see if I can get one tomorrow

Comment: @zipo13 but it basically stretches the video vertically and makes it look ugly

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get support preview sizes and calculate your optimal width and height from it.

for example

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }
```

Then use it inside onMeasure Method to get optimum preview size

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
           mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }
```

Then inside surfaceChanged set your camera parameters

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
mCamera.startPreview();
```

Comment: I would like to say it works but since I am using a custom made `Camera` I cannot use `onMeasure()` and thus i cant use the functions `resolveSize` and `getSuggestedMinimumWidth()`